# Limit row's height on both "Auto" and "1*" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

I have a WPF application which layout consists of 3 rows in a top level `Grid`.

I want the middle row to use up the space it needs (the maximum space it needs is limited but depends on the width of the window).
The bottom row shall use up the remaining space.
The tricky part is the top row.
Its size can vary depending on a button which toggles the visibility of a large part of the content. I want it to use at most 50% of the height but not more than it really needs.
The following XAML describes what I want to accomplish:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- neither "1*" nor "Auto" fully meets my needs -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Min(1*,Auto)"></RowDefinition>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The rows are:

1. `WrapPanel`
2. `WrapPanel`
3. `TextBox`

if this is important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand it right, you could probably use `Auto` and then bind the `MaxHeight` attribute to the `Height` of the `Grid`. Maybe something like this:

MaxHeightConverter.cs:

```
public class MaxHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("MaxHeightConverter expects a height value", "values");

        return ((double)value / 2);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MyWindow.xaml:

```
...
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Namespace"
...
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:MaxHeightConverter x:Key="MaxHeightValue" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="root">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WrapPanel >
        <WrapPanel.MaxHeight>
            <Binding Converter="{StaticResource MaxHeightValue}" ElementName="root" Path="ActualHeight" />
        </WrapPanel.MaxHeight>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Works exactly the way I want it. I just had to change the cast from `(int)` to `(double)` in the `MaxHeightConverter`.

Answer (score 7):

Another way you could do this with only XAML would be binding to a hidden object that is the height you want:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="White" Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="HalfHeightRow" x:FieldModifier="private" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Height="1000" Background="Red" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=HalfHeightRow}" />
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Height="100" Background="Green" />
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. It may be useful for me in more complex situations. But for now I'll stick with Jespers solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could make Matt's suggestion even simpler and clearer.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" x:Name="HalfHeightRow"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=HalfHeightRow}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Height="1000" Background="Red" />
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Height="100" Background="Green" />
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Blue" />
    </Grid>
```