# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn, bind to generic CellTemplate

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datagridtemplatecolumn

I'm very new to WPF so sorry if this is obvious but I can't seem to find any decent examples on the internet showing how it's done.

I have a DataGrid which is bound to a collection of DataItem called MyCollection.  I want to create a generic DataTemplate that I can use for multiple columns in the grid (and elsewhere in the application should I need it).

E.g.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" EnableColumnVirtualization="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="File path" CellTemplate="{StaticResource FileSelectorEditorTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource FileSelectorEditorTemplate}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="File path2" CellTemplate="{StaticResource FileSelectorEditorTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource FileSelectorEditorTemplate}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="File path3" CellTemplate="{StaticResource FileSelectorEditorTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource FileSelectorEditorTemplate}" />
...
```

My DataTemplate is defined at the moment in my Application resources as

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FileSelectorEditorTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FilePath.PhysicalPath}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,35,0" />
            <Button Content="..." Height="25" Width="25" Margin="0,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="FileOpen_Click" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now the problem is that the binding is specified in the DataTemplate, whereas I need to apply a different binding for each of the properties FilePath, FilePath2, FilePath3 on the view model.  I don't seem to be able to specify the Binding on the DataGridTemplateColumn though?

I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction,

Thanks!

Comment: i thinks it should help you   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43525/WPF-DataGrid-Using-DataTemplates-for-auto-generate

Answer (score 0):

The binding on the `DataGridTemplateColumn` is specified in its `CellTemplate`. 
If you want different bindings for the three columns, I'd say you would have to make a different `DataTemplate` for each of the columns. There might be some workaround, but I doubt it would be pretty.

Edit:
Having different templates you can use a `DataTemplateSelector` to select the right template for the current object.

Using IValueConverter (Just a quick sketch, but should work):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GenericTemplate" >
        <TextBlock FontSize="14" >
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource NewValue}" Path="Me" />
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>

public class NewValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        someContainer obj = value as someContainer;
        if (obj.type == MyType.First)
             return (string)(obj.val1);
        else
             return (string)(obj.val2);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public enum MyType
{
    First,
    Second
}

public class someContainer
{
    public someContainer Me { get; set; }
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
    public MyType type;

    public someContainer()
    {
        Me = this;
        val1 = "string1";
        val2 = "string2";
    }     
}

...
public ObservableCollection<someContainer> myList {get; set;}
...

<StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GenericTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: That seems ridiculous to me. Surely there must be a way in WPF to create a common template that I can reuse throughout the application for different properties of the same type?

Comment: Maybe you could use an `IValueConverter` on the binding in the `DataTemplate`. I posted an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860046/limit-rows-height-on-both-auto-and-1-in-wpf/13860478#13860478

Comment: Thanks Jesper, but I'm not sure that helps? Wouldn't I still have the problem of how to specify the binding in the data template?

Comment: Added some quick code for the `IValueConverter`, the way I see it could be done. Not the prettiest solution but should work.

Comment: Just realized this won't solve your problem specifying the binding at the column.. No immediate ideas for that, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the option of Jesper Gaarsdal you might also be able to use a CellStyle and define the binding in the column-declaration.

see this SO for example: [How to reuse WPF DataGridTemplateColumn (including binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849460/how-to-reuse-wpf-datagridtemplatecolumn-including-binding)